# Slow asset pipeline/static files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, cdn, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I recently implemented Capistrano for the first time with a new cloud production environment. When I run `cap deploy`, everything seems to work fine. I can visit my live application in the browser, but my static files seem to load very slowly (like 5.0-12.0s).

See answer for clarity on `config.assets.compile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files load slowly because they possibly are not static, but are being served by Sprockets.

Check in production.rb and see if `config.assets.compile = true` or it is not set. That would mean that Sprockets is doing the work. You would also see far-future headers being used.

Have a look in `/home/my_user/my_app/current/public` and see if `assets` exists; I suspect it does not.

That means that `mkdir -p` is not working. The most likely cause is that the deploy user does not have sufficient permissions to create the directory.

Fix that, and also check (if this is an upgraded app from 3.0 or before) that your config setting match those in the [last section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails) of the pipeline guide.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I misunderstood the comment `# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed`. If `config.assets.compile = true`, then it will compile each at runtime even if they were precompiled.

Comment: Regarding the `cap deploy`, the assets are being successfully compiled. They reappear if I remove the assets folder manually and then `cap deploy` again. If I ssh in (as the same user) and run the mkdir -p /... command, there is no permission issue. Is this something I missed in deploy.rb?

Comment: If compile is true then the Sprockets handles requests for assets if they do not exist in `public/assets` (The default is false). If it is false then your app will return a 404 for missing assets. Are you using the standard deploy script (by including `load 'deploy/assets'`) in your Capfile?

Comment: This was really two questions, and you solved the main pain point. I have moved the [more difficult one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918416/capistrano-output-err).